# How to compare two files line by line

Tags: ruby, text

I want to check two files `'file1.txt'` and `'file2.txt'` and print the lines that are common. How do I do it? The following are what I have in the files:

file1.txt:

```
 An insightful look into the scenario of academic integrity and its implications give us the major motivation
 for pursuing the subject. The issue holds utmost significance as the intellectual standards of an individual
 pursuing an academia a reestablished around his ability to produce authoritative work. Plagiarism is thus lethal.
 Every year a large number of students and scholars submit a huge volume of material to their respective mentors and professors
```

file2.txt:

```
An insightful look into the scenario of academic integrity and its implications give us the major motivation
 for pursuing the subject. The issue holds utmost significance as the intellectual standards of an individual 
pursuing an academia a reestablished around his ability to produce authoritative work. Plagiarism is thus lethal. 
Every year a large number of students and scholars submit a huge volume of material to their respective mentors and professors. 
Due to the sheer amount of text involved, a manual Result and conclusion follow where we present our observations and learning.
```

Comment: your code not working ?

Comment: the code which i have posted works! but in that it just compares the whole file.I wanna check line by line and print only those lines which are equal

Comment: Starting to look more and more like an XY-problem.

Comment: what is an XY problem?

Comment: @SanjanaGurukar Google is your friend: [What is the XY problem? - Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use external iterators to compare line pairs from different files one by one, something like this:

```
lines1 = File.readlines('file1.txt').each
lines2 = File.readlines('file2.txt').each

begin
  i = 0
  while true
    puts "line #{i +=1 }:"
    puts line1 = lines1.next
    puts line2 = lines2.next
    puts "identical: #{line1 == line2 ? 'yes' : 'no'}\n\n"
  end
rescue StopIteration
end
```

If you don't care about leading and trailing spaces, then you can use [String#strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-strip) - `line1.strip == line2.strip`. The loop will stop when and end of either file is reached.

The output produced with `line1.strip == line2.strip` is as follows:

```
line 1:
 An insightful look into the scenario of academic integrity and its implications give us the major motivation
An insightful look into the scenario of academic integrity and its implications give us the major motivation
identical: yes

line 2:
 for pursuing the subject. The issue holds utmost significance as the intellectual standards of an individual
 for pursuing the subject. The issue holds utmost significance as the intellectual standards of an individual 
identical: yes

line 3:
 pursuing an academia a reestablished around his ability to produce authoritative work. Plagiarism is thus lethal.
pursuing an academia a reestablished around his ability to produce authoritative work. Plagiarism is thus lethal. 
identical: yes

line 4:
 Every year a large number of students and scholars submit a huge volume of material to their respective mentors and professors
Every year a large number of students and scholars submit a huge volume of material to their respective mentors and professors. 
identical: no

line 5:
```

Answer (score 2):

Edited following Arup's suggestion.

```
puts File.readlines("file1.txt") & File.readlines("file2.txt")
```

Comment: Hehe,. It is so easy, it seems... :)

Comment: Note: _Under the hood it compares the elements using `eql?` with their `hash` value_ Short explanation about how `&` works... :)

Comment: it just reads two files and i am not getting any output, I want to print the common lines in both files after comparing line by line

Comment: @SanjanaGurukar If your files do not have common lines, then you don't get any output.

Comment: obvi, but i have same lines

Comment: @SanjanaGurukar Show some portions of it.

Comment: file1.txt : An insightful look into the scenario of academic integrity and its implications give us the major motivation for pursuing the subject. The issue holds utmost significance as the intellectual standards of an individual pursuing an academia a reestablished around his ability to produce authoritative work. Plagiarism is thus lethal. Every year a large number of students and scholars submit a huge volume of material to their respective mentors and professors.

Comment: file2.txt : An insightful look into the scenario of academic integrity and its implications give us the major motivation for pursuing the subject. The issue holds utmost significance as the intellectual standards of an individual pursuing an academia a reestablished around his ability to produce authoritative work. Plagiarism is thus lethal. Every year a large number of students and scholars submit a huge volume of material to their respective mentors and professors. Due to the sheer amount of text involved, a manual Result and conclusion follow where we present our observations and learning.

Comment: @SanjanaGurukar Don't put it in the comment. Add it the question. And make clear where the linebreaks are.

Comment: @SanjanaGurukar Now it became clear that you do not have any identical lines in the two files.

Comment: how? both files are 90% same know?

Comment: @SanjanaGurukar There is no same line. Which line are you claiming to be the same?

Comment: the first line atleast

Comment: @SanjanaGurukar file1.txt starts with `' '` (space), file2.txt starts with `'A'`

Comment: but both are the same! Am just trying to do plagiarism check here. How would I do it efficiently?